# Format hard drive without starting windows

Tags: hard-drive, boot, operating-systems, format, filesystem-corruption

My hard drive must be corrupted/missing files etc. I cant boot any windows install/linux. Because i currently can't launch any OS (I also tried running dban to complete wipe my hard drive but there was a cat error can't open cmd line.),how can i format my hdd if i can't boot to anything? Is there another program that i can download like dban? Or is there another way to format my hard drive?

Comment: You can connect the HDD to another system, and within an operating system that is running on that system, format the HDD.  You could alternatively determine the reason you are unable to boot into any installation environment.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Apparently you have two Super User accounts: [this one](//superuser.com/users/922849/user922849) and [this one](//superuser.com/users/922850/user922850). Please take the time to utilize [this Help Center tutorial](//superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You have two solutions:

- Take your HDD out of your computer, connect it to another computer and format it from there
- Use a live DVD/USB to boot into a temporary OS and wipe your HDD

Note that after wiping your disk you *will* have to completely reinstall an OS, so I higly suggest solution #2 since almost every live medium comes with its own installer.

Answer (score 0):

If your PC firmware permits, you can go to an [EFI shell prompt](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/efi-shells-and-scripting) and then run [diskpart](https://ss64.com/nt/diskpart.html) then enter these commands to create an EFI/GPT partition table, activate the drive, and create a GPT partition table so it can be formatted by the installer:

```
diskpart
list disk 
sel disk 0
clean
list disk
convert gpt 
list disk
exit
```